# MySQL - 1 query but return two array's?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I was wondering if it is possible to send one query to mysql but receive two array's?

```
$query = 'SELECT a.username,b.* FROM users a, posts b WHERE b.user_id = a.id';
```

This should return an array like

```
array(
    'postid' => 1,
    'title' => 'this is a title',
    'body' => 'this is a body',
    'user' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'username' => 'name'
    )
)
```

The current query returns one 'mixed' array with the user and post together.

Comment: i know how to limit it, but what i ment was if there is a possibility to make mysql return seperate array's of the two tables that i'm sending the request to

Comment: It's impossible. That's it.

Comment: You have to generate the array manually then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at MVC Pattern.
You can create a model like `Post` with the Attributes `postid`, `title`, `body` and `user` as array. After your SQL you can fill the model. Then you can access to the data in the model.

**Example:**

```
class Post {
   private $title;

   public function setTitle($title) {
       $this->title = $title;
   }
   public function getTitle() {
       return $this->title;
   }
}
```

To get your desirable result with you query is not possible.